# Why i cannot get a JSON response data in Javascript? with axios+express

Tags: javascript, json, get, request, response

I'm trying to get the lyrics as a response to this simple lyrics request (of an Eminem song for example) , it doesn't give me any errors but I don't understand why I'm not getting the response. **What am i missing?**
Please help me :)

```
app.get('/lyrics', function(req, res)
{
  axios.get('https://api.lyrics.ovh/v1/eminem/stan')
    .then(function(data)
    {
      let result = {
        lyrics : data['lyrics'],
      };
      res.status(200).send(result);
    })
    .catch(function(err)
    {
      if(err['statusCode'] == 404)
        res.send({error : {status : 404, message : 'Lyrics not found'}});
      else
        res.send(err);
    })
    .then(function () {
    // always executed
    });
});
```

Comment: Axios resolves with a [Response](https://axios-http.com/docs/res_schema) object. The data is in the `data` property so you would want `data.data.lyrics` or `.then(function({ data }) { ... })`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As Phil Mentioned, Edit your code to this and you'll be fine

```
app.get('/lyrics', function(req, res)
{
  axios.get('https://api.lyrics.ovh/v1/eminem/stan')
    .then(function(data)
    {
      let result = {
        lyrics : data.data.lyrics,
      };
      res.status(200).send(result);
    })
    .catch(function(err)
    {
      if(err['statusCode'] == 404)
        res.send({error : {status : 404, message : 'Lyrics not found'}});
      else
        res.send(err);
    })
    .then(function () {
    
    });
});
```